# Use switch case for tabs on a nav bar

Tags: javascript, css, switch-statement, arcgis-js-api

I would like to use the switch case to display certain features only on certain tabs. I have a basemap toggle which is  in my html that I would like turned off on my last tab by displaying it to none in css. Any suggestions? I already have a switch case for the tooltips on each tab in the navbar. It looks like this:

```
let tabs = $('.entries > .nav > .entry > .entryLbl ');
        tabs.each(function (idx, liItem) {
            switch (liItem.text) {
                case 'Electric':
                    //liItem.on('click', function () {
                    //    console.log('got a click on electric');
                    //});
                    liItem.setAttribute('title', 'To download a Los Angeles Substructure Plan: \n 1. Zoom to a substructure quad\n 2. Click the area inside the quad \n 3. Click "More info"');
                    document.getElementById('BasemapToggle').style.display="none" 
                    break;
                case 'Gas/Oil':
                    liItem.setAttribute('title', 'This tab contains non-hazardous gas/oil utilities. Visit our confidential \n gas/oil application at: http://sv07gis6/undergroundconfidential');
                    break;
                case 'Sanitation':
                    liItem.setAttribute('title', 'Download LA City SanGIS Data in its entirety at:\n http://geohub.lacity.org/datasets?q=sewer \nDownload LACSD GIS Data in its entirety at:\n http://data-lacsdgis.opendata.arcgis.com');
                    break;
                case 'Stormwater':
                    liItem.setAttribute('title', 'Download LA County Stormwater GIS Data in its entirety at: \n http://dpw.lacounty.gov/fcd/stormdrain/disclaimer.cfm \n and click "File Geodatabase Download"');
                    break;
                case 'Download':
                    liItem.setAttribute('title', 'Use this tab to download snippets of all utility types within\n up to a 500-foot range in .shp or .dgn formats');
                    break;
                case 'Resources':
                    liItem.setAttribute('title', 'Please contact D7GIS to help with our resources list');
                    break;
            }
        })      
  });
```

Much Thanks,
Brandon

Answer (score 0):

Use straight css to target the last li (assuming you are using a ul / li structure for your nav)

```
.entries > .nav > li:last-of-type {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a good use for a switch. If it is the last tab you want to affect use:

```
tabs.last().css('display','none');
```

Or inside your each:

```
tabs.each(function (idx, liItem) {
    switch [..]
    if($(this).is(':last-child')) $(this).css('display','none');
})
```

Comment: thanks for the comments guys. I was able to get it to half work using: $('.entries > .nav > .entry > .entryLbl:not(:last-child)').click(function() {
    $("#streetv").show();
   });
  $('.entries > .nav > .entry > .entryLbl ').last().click(function() {
    $("#streetv").hide();                                                                                              However, when my last child (last tab) is clicked and my button goes away, as soon as I go back to any of the other tabs, the button never reappears.

Comment: So you want your last tab hidden conditionally? What is the condition, when it should be hidden?

Comment: Hi everybody. I was able to resolve this by using                       
      $(liItem).click( function () {
                        $('#streetv').show();

Comment: when I wanted the button to be seen and "hide" when not on certain tabs.